# Python | Sorting out redundant text from screen scraper application

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm writing a screen scraper application monitoring a text-only chat window. Text is added at the bottom of the window.

The application takes screenshot of the chat window. If a change has occurred since last screenshot (new_screenshot != old_screenshot), the screenshot is saved.

After X time, all images are merged to one image, where the oldest image is on the top. This large image is send to a server for OCR, and a string of text is returned.

**Problem:** How to sort out redundant text?

Example:

- Chat window is 5 lines high and is initially empty.
- The solution must work with empty and not-empty initial chat window.
- More than one line can be added at each screenshot. The same line can come multiple times, **but never two times in a row** so just deduplicating is not enough (so using `sorted(set(text.split('\n')))` would not be sufficiant)

**Input to algorithm:**

1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum.
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum.
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet.
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
2 consectetur adipiscing elit
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum.
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet.
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique.
2 consectetur adipiscing elit 
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum. 
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet. 
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique. 
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna. 
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum.
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet.
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique.
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna.
7 Proin pretium, metus non porttitor lobortis, tortor sem rhoncus urna
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet.
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique.
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna.
7 Proin pretium, metus non porttitor lobortis, tortor sem rhoncus urna
8 quis finibus leo lorem sed lacus.
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique.
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna.
7 Proin pretium, metus non porttitor lobortis, tortor sem rhoncus urna
8 quis finibus leo lorem sed lacus.
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

**Expected result:**

1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
2 consectetur adipiscing elit 
 
3 Mauris porttitor enim sed tincidunt interdum. 
4 Morbi elementum erat nec nulla auctor, eget porta odio aliquet. 
5 Nam aliquet velit vel elementum tristique. 
6 Donec ac tincidunt urna. 
7 Proin pretium, metus non porttitor lobortis, tortor sem rhoncus urna 
8 quis finibus leo lorem sed lacus. 
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

Comment: Why is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet removed after first one but reappears only at the end?

Comment: To illustrate that the exact same line can reappear, and should only be ignored if the two similar lines appears twice in a row

Comment: Something like this http://tpcg.io/4GcfOx ?

Comment: Well it does produce the expected output, but is the logic what you were seeking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code from what I understood you want (add new lines seen but keeping a history of 5 lines to avoid repeats):

```
history = 5
lastSeen = dict()
result = [] 
for idx, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
    if line not in lastSeen:
        result.append(line)
    else:
        if lastSeen[line] + history < idx:
            result.append(line)
    lastSeen[line] = idx
```